# Python Polars: How to add a progress bars to apply loops

Tags: python, python-polars

Is it possible to add a **progress bar** to a Polars **apply loop with a custom function**?

For example, how would I add a progress bar to the following toy example:

```
        import polars as pl

        df = pl.DataFrame(
            {
                "team": ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C"],
                "conference": ["East", "East", "East", "West", "West", "East"],
                "points": [11, 8, 10, 6, 6, 5],
                "rebounds": [7, 7, 6, 9, 12, 8]
            }
        )

        df.groupby('team').apply(lambda x: x.select(pl.col('points').mean()))
```

**Edit 1:**

After help from @Jcurious, I have the following 'tools' that can be re-used for other functions, however it does not print to console correctly.

```
        def pl_progress_applier(func, task_id, progress, **kwargs):
            progress.update(task_id, advance=1, refresh=True)
            return func(**kwargs)

        def pl_groupby_progress_apply(data, group_by, func, drop_cols=[], **kwargs):

            global progress
            with Progress() as progress:
                num_groups = len(data.select(group_by).unique())
                task_id = progress.add_task("Applying", total=num_groups)
                return (
                    data
                        .groupby(group_by)
                        .apply(lambda x: pl_progress_applier(
                            x=x.drop(drop_cols), func=func, task_id=task_id, progress=progress, **kwargs)
                        )
                )

        # and using the function custom_func, we can return a table, howevef the progress bar jumps to 100%

        def custom_func(x):
            return x.select(pl.col('points').mean())

        pl_groupby_progress_apply(
            data=df,
            group_by='team',
            func=custom_func
        )
```

Any ideas on how to get the progress bar to actually work?

**Edit 2:**

It seems like the above functions do indeed work, however if you're using PyCharm (like me), then it does not work. Enjoy non-PyCharm users!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [rich.progress](https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/stable/progress.html) which also comes bundled with pip.

`progress.update()` can manually update a progress bar.

```
from pip._vendor.rich.progress import Progress

def my_custom_function(group):
    progress.update(task_id, advance=1)
    return group.select(pl.col('points').mean())
   
with Progress() as progress:     
    num_groups = df.get_column("team").unique().len()
    task_id = progress.add_task("Applying", total=num_groups)
    
    df.groupby('team').apply(my_custom_function)
```

Although perhaps you should share what you're actually doing as `.groupby.apply()` is going to be "slow" - there may be a better way.

Comment: The key is that you need to actually define the apply function and not use lambda since it's more than a one line at that point.  You could just as easily create a function that just prints stuff.  Of course there's a bit of a contradiction in terms since anything in the apply is not really polars anymore but I digress.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor I had `.apply(lambda x: [progress.update(task_id, advance=1), x.select(pl.col('points').mean())][-1])` in a previous revision but edited it.

Comment: I guess I'm confusing the should not use lambda for more than one-liners with can't.  I didn't mean my comment as a criticism of the answer, more a clarification for OP.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor Yeah, I guess it's an "abuse" of list syntax, which is why I changed it. I did not interpret it as a criticism, I was just trying to point out that "technically" it is possible with a lambda which may be of interest to you/others.

Comment: @jqurious is there a way to wrap this into a custom function, so it can be re-used?

Comment: @Sharma I don't see why not, are you having trouble trying to do that? How are you planning on structuring it?  Something like `progress(df, group, func)` ?

Comment: @jqurious correct - I'll edit my question to put the functions I currently have for it, but unfortunately the progress bar does not update per loop/group.

Comment: @jqurious question edited. If you can see why my functions do not work, that would be great :)

Comment: Okay well in this example `custom_func` executes so fast it goes straight to 100% - Try put `time.sleep(1)` in before the return statement you should see the progress bar.

Comment: @jqurious mhmm. I've put in time.sleep(5) and it behaves the same e.g. only printing progress when everything is complete.

Comment: @jqurious Okay no. It looks like my pip._vendor.rich.progress version does not work correctly? I have tried your 1st solution and even that does not print correctly. Has this happened to you before?

Comment: This is what happens when I run your code with a `time.sleep(1)` https://i.imgur.com/dgYAfqO.mp4

Comment: Apologies @jqurious it looks like the issues I'm having are due to PyCharm and not the rich package. I'll mark your answer as the solution and figure this out separately. Tyvm Jqurious, great work again :)

Answer (score 3):

The best solution I found is tqdm. We want a solution that

1. enable us stay in the polars coding style.
2. General

To do so, all we have to define is this function:

```
import polars as pl
from tqdm import tqdm

def w_pbar(pbar, func):
    def foo(*args, **kwargs):
        pbar.update(1)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return foo
```

Now, we could take your original code, generate pbar and add 'w_pbar' in the appropriate place:

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "team": ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C"],
        "conference": ["East", "East", "East", "West", "West", "East"],
        "points": [11, 8, 10, 6, 6, 5],
        "rebounds": [7, 7, 6, 9, 12, 8]
    }
)
num_groups = df.get_column("team").unique().len()
with tqdm(total=num_groups) as pbar:
    res = df.groupby('team').apply(w_pbar(pbar, lambda x: x.select(pl.col('points').mean())))
```

You can generate pbar (the tqdm object) with every setting you want. And add w_pbar to any usage of 'apply'.

bty, it also works for 'apply' without 'groupby':

```
pbar = tqdm(total=len(df), desc='adding 1 to points', colour='green')
df1 = df.with_columns(pl.col('points').apply(w_pbar(pbar, lambda x: x + 1)).alias('points+1'))
pbar.close()
```

Comment: It works in pycharm for me.