# Polars apply function bindingserror

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a function call it text_scores that takes a string, and returns a list of tuples, where each tuple has two elements: a string and a float number. I'm trying to apply this function on a column (call it "text") in a dataframe by using polars.

So far I have this:

```
df_polar.with_columns([pl.col("text").apply(lambda x: text_scores(classifier(x))))
```

It gives me this error: BindingsError: "object type not supported ('happy', 0.234)"

'happy' and 0.234 were generated from the classifier.

The classifier generates a dictionary like this if you provide it with a text:

```
{ 'labels': ['happy', 'sad', 'optimistic', 'angry'],
'scores': [0.234, 0.12, 0.34, 0.05]
}
```

How would you write this in order to avoid this error?

```
def text_scores(dict_vals):
    return [(label,score) for label, score in zip(dict_vals['labels'], dict_vals['scores'])]
```

Comment: You could use `dict(str_proc(x))` if the keys are unique to get a struct column. Ideally though - you would use polars expressions instead of `.apply()` and `str_proc`. Can you show what `str_proc` does exactly?

Comment: @jqurious I modified the question. I hope now it's more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you leave out the `text_scores` function and pass the dictionary back - polars will create a `struct` column:

```
df.with_columns(pl.col("text").apply(lambda x: classifier()))
```

```
shape: (1, 1)
┌─────────────────────────────────────┐
│ text                                │
│ ---                                 │
│ struct[2]                           │
╞═════════════════════════════════════╡
│ {["happy", "sad", ... "angry"],[... │
└─────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Which you could then `.unnest()` if desired:

```
shape: (1, 2)
┌───────────────────────────────┬─────────────────────────┐
│ labels                        | scores                  │
│ ---                           | ---                     │
│ list[str]                     | list[f64]               │
╞═══════════════════════════════╪═════════════════════════╡
│ ["happy", "sad", ... "angry"] | [0.234, 0.12, ... 0.05] │
└───────────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────┘
```

Compared to what is currently happening:

```
df.with_columns(pl.col("text").apply(lambda x: text_scores(classifier())))
```

```
ComputeError: RuntimeError: BindingsError: "object type not supported ('happy', 0.234)"
```

Example code used:

```
import polars as pl

def classifier():
    return {
        "labels": ["happy", "sad", "optimistic", "angry"],
        "scores": [0.234, 0.12, 0.34, 0.05],
    }

def text_scores(dict_vals):
    return [
        (label, score) 
        for label, score in zip(dict_vals["labels"], dict_vals["scores"])
    ]
```

Comment: the classifier function takes as an argument a string (a text). So does the syntax change now?

Comment: Well yes, you would use `lambda x: classifier(x)` from your example - does that not work for you?

Comment: It worked perfectly as you said with unnest. But I still don't know how to make a new column (call it "labels_scores") with values [('happy',0.234), ('sad',0.12), ('optimistic',0.34), ('angry',0.05)]

Comment: I don't think that's possible as polars columns are typed. If you use lists instead of tuples. e.g. `return [[label,score] for ...` polars will build a nested list column - but the floats will be casted to strings.

Comment: One more question: does polars have a progress bar like tqdm?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. You could use `tdqm` - there's an example using `rich.progress`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75550124/python-polars-how-to-add-a-progress-bars-to-apply-loops - I'm guessing `tqdm` should be able to work in a similar way. Maybe there is a polars/tqdm example out there - I've never looked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252421/discussion-between-guess601-and-jqurious).